# How to access dropdownlist selected value in flutter and use it in another widget

Tags: flutter, dart

**This is my drop down list code**

```
  String dropdownValue = "a";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) { 
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
      items: <String>[
        'a','b','c'
      ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

**I want to use the selected value here**

```
  uploadDatatoFirebase() async {
*firebase connection code*
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(**selected value in drop down**) // the value from the box goes here
 
  }
```

I can't seem to find a solution please help i want to create a database depending on the select box value any other techniques will also be welcomed

Comment: Check if you have firebase configured for the project. If yes, then you can call `uploadDatatoFirebase` after setState. Assuming the method is in the same widget, you should be able to access dropdownValue in your uploadDatatoFirebase method.

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/get_it This is the package I use so I can can access a single instance of a class anywhere in the app, it is very popular and very well maintained. You could do this

```
setState(() {
   dropdownValue = newValue!;
   GetIt.I.get<ControllerWhatever>().selectedValueInDropDown = newValue!;
})
```

Just register the 'global controller instance' just as described in the get_it page and you will be able to get the value from any attribute you want anywhere in your app. It will make you life a lot easier

Comment: Can you help me with the syntax i can't make out much with the documentation